# Simple JQuery Fade In/Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fadein, fadeout

So what I'm trying to do is getting a div with an animation to show up only when I hover a button. I want that div to be invisible until the page hovers it, and I want it to go back being invisible once the mouse is no longer hovering the button.
Also, I want to do this with JQuery since I've kept far away from it for too long.

JQuery Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $('#about').hover(function(){
            $('#about_hover').stop(true, true).animate({
                width: '150px',
                opacity: '0.8',
            }, 300);
        }, function(){
            $('#about_hover').animate({
                width: '0px',
                opacity: '0',
            }, 300);
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="about_hover">
    <img src="images/hover.gif">
</div>
<a href="about.html" id="about"><img src="images/menu/about.png"></a>
<br>
```

CSS:

```
#about_hover { 
    text-align: right;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'm getting a few problems though. First of all, the image inside the div loads up with opacity at 100% and only goes to 80% after I hover it for the first time. After that, it fades away like it's supposed to but it doesn't show up again when I hover the button.

Any thoughts?
Thanks
Thanks!

Comment: No need for a stop on the "off" hover?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. I think the animation of the width is a little odd but it's fine code-wise. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/45nHH/

Comment: Could it be related to other css elements I have? It works fine in jsFiddle.

Comment: It's working fine in Firefox, Opera and Safari. Doesn't work with Chrome though.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [**fadeTo**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) or [**fadeToogle**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) ?

Here's a small snippet made using fadeTo:  **http://jsbin.com/agojux** ?

you can have a look at it's source **[here](http://jsbin.com/agojux/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's probably best to use jQuery's `on` in this situation.. Your code would look something like this:

```
$("selector").on({

mouseenter: function () {
 //fade in goes here
},

mouseleave: function () {
//fade out goes here
 }
});
```

Hover is cool and all, but things can get messy with hover toggling.  `on` makes this a snap.  Also for your opacity's, I would probably use a `fadeTo` instead.

[Here is the on documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: just a quick note, bind is deprecated the preference is to use $('selector').on

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ayezutov/45nHH/2/) is your code, but a little bit modified:

JS:

```
$('#about_hover').width(0);        
$('#about').hover(function(){
            $('#about_hover').stop(true, true).animate({
                width: '150px',
                opacity: '0.8',
            }, 300);
        }, function(){
            $('#about_hover').animate({
                width: '0px',
                opacity: '0',
            }, 300);
        });​
```

HTML:

```
<a href="about.html" id="about"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/20/20/"></a><br>
<div id="about_hover"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/80/80/"></div>
```

Comment: I'm gonna try the bind. As for the code you posted Alexander, it doesn't seem to work. The image doesn't animate at all with those modifications :S

Comment: `Bind` won't bring you any benefits. But if want to try, use better [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as a more modern alternative. `Bind` is said to be outdated

Comment: BTW, my example worked for me in Chrome17 and IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/ayezutov/45nHH/2/

Comment: I tried using the code in Chrome and IE and nothing happened.